# Who are the basis for the characters in Shikkoku no Sharnoth

Tags: shikkoku-no-sharnoth

Looking at VNDB's character page for [Shikkoku no Sharnoth ~What a Beautiful Tomorrow~](https://vndb.org/v1027/chars#chars) some of the characters have under their Role section, either *"Based on a Real Person"* or *"Based on a Fictional Person"*

Character's like *Sherlock* and *Churchill* i get who their basis is just from their name's. *Mary's* basis is revealed at the end when she signs the book she finished writing with the pen name *Agatha Christie* (though it's mentioned a number of times at the start that she's a writer if that wasn't a bug enough clue)

but there are character's like *Charlotte Brontë* who are based off real characters who i don't recognize while there are characters like *Sebastian Moran* who are based off fictional character who i am interested in knowing if they fictional basis is any different with how they are presented in Shikkoku no Sharnoth

So i am asking for a List of all the characters of *Shikkoku no Sharnoth ~What a Beautiful Tomorrow~* who have a **Based on a ______ Person** tag and who their character basis is. completion wise also include obvious characters like Sherlock and Churchill

Answer (score 1):

I haven't played this game, but I recognize a few of the references.

- Mary Clarissia Christie is a reference to mystery novelist Agatha Christie.
- Angelica Derleth may be a reference to horror writer August Derleth, who wrote stories set in HP Lovecraft's fictional universe.
- Bram Stoker is the author of *Dracula*.
- Charlotte Brontë is named for the author of *Jane Eyre*.
- Colonel Sebastian Moran was a character in the Sherlock Holmes universe. He was the henchman of Holmes's nemesis, Professor Moriarty, and an expert marksman; in "The Adventure of the Empty House", he tries to shoot Holmes.
- Elly Beinhorn was [a German aviator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elly_Beinhorn). She would have been a child in 1905, when the game takes place; her period of activity was in the 1930s.
- [Henry Irving](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Henry_Irving) was an English stage actor which Wikipedia claims was the inspiration for the character of Dracula in Bram Stoker's novel.
- [Josef Čapek](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Josef_%C4%8Capek) was a Czech painter and brother of Karl Čapek, the playwright who introduced the word "robot". According to Wikipedia, Josef invented the word "robot".
- Winston Churchill was British Prime Minister during World War II.
- Baron Munchausen is, according to [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baron_Munchausen), "a fictional German nobleman in literature and film, loosely based on a real baron, Hieronymus Karl Friedrich, Freiherr von Münchhausen".
- George Lestrade is based on Inspector Lestrade, a police officer from the Sherlock Holmes stories who acts as one of Holmes's contacts with the police force.
- [Heinz Heger](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heinz_Heger) was the penname of the author of the book *The Men With the Pink Triangle*, which is about the experience of homosexuals in concentration camps under the Nazis.
- Howard Philips is probably a reference to horror author HP Lovecraft, whose full name was Howard Philips Lovecraft. He is the author of "Call of Chthulu" and "The Dream-Quest of Unknown Kadath". [Lovecraft's Wikipedia article](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/H._P._Lovecraft#Lovecraft_as_a_character_in_fiction) also makes this claim, without citation.
- Keynes may be a reference to economist John Maynard Keynes.
- Marie Hudson may be a reference to Mrs. Hudson, the landlady of 221B Baker Street, where Sherlock Holmes and James Watson resided.
- Sherlock Holmes is the famous fictional detective.
- Arthur Conan Doyle is the author who created Sherlock Holmes.